# What data transfer rates are needed or streaming HD 1080p or 720p video, or standard quality video?

Tags: streaming, data-transfer

Want to know data transfer rates for streaming video, such as from an external hard drive, or from an NAS or a home network. All I'm asking about is the data transfer speeds for clean video streaming.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That depends entirely on the codecs and their settings. For example the standard values for Blu-ray Discs are:

```
MPEG-4 AVC Video at 18000 kbps for 1080p
MPEG-4 AVC Video at  8000 kbps for  720p
DTS-HD Master Audio
```

The bit rate of the audio codec is variable, but should stay under 4 Mbps. That's a total of **22 Mbps** for 1080p and **12 Mbps** for 720p. Lossy compression may result in much lower bit rates.

In comparison, some transfer speeds<sup>1</sup>:

- USB 1.1 (full bandwidth): 12 Mbps
- USB 2.0: 480 Mbps
- PATA: up to 1064 Mbps
- SATA I: 1500 Mbps
- Ethernet<sup>2</sup>: 10 Mbps
- Fast Ethernet<sup>2</sup>: 100 Mbps
- Gigabit Ethernet<sup>2</sup>: 1000 Mbps

Even USB 1.1 *could* be fast enough for 720p. USB 2.0 and every modern hard drive should be fast enough for 1080p.

With Ethernet, it depends entirely on the speed of the involved components and other network activity. If all components support Fast Ethernet, the transfer speeds *should* be fast enough for 1080p.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For effective transfer speeds, protocol overhead has to be taken into account.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>This is not a standard. In practice, an Ethernet connection labelled as, e.g., *Fast Ethernet* could have a a different transfer speed.</sub>

Comment: "Other codecs are generally more efficient." – MPEG-4 AVC is *the* most efficient codec today.

Comment: I was thinking about H.264, but I just found out that MPEG-4 AVC *is* H.264, so silly me.

Comment: Something else that needs to be taken into account is the transfer rate of your storage media. Mechanical hard drives will struggle to much beyond 800 Mbps. SSDs will be faster but not by much. Of course both of these are way above the video's bitrates so it's probably a moot point.

Comment: just a note, 800mbps will transfer 1GB of data in 10 seconds.

Comment: Where did you find the bit rates for those video formats for Blu-Ray pleaes?